# Timeout for website rather than single webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

I am working on a website hwere i need to introduce security for reasons, my website automatically signs users out after 10 minutes of inactivity. The behavior is, at about 8 minutes of inactivity, a jquery ui dialog pops up, warning the user of their impending timeout. The user can choose to stay signed in, sign out now, or do nothing and they are forced to sign out at the end of the 10 minutes. I achieve this through a javascript code snippet that timeouts (no mouse/keyboard event) and reset any time the user does what I consider an "activity".

My problem is i can make this thing run for my single webpage but have no clue how to use this for complete domain. I have thought of cookies to achieve this feat as well but not very sure. If someone can suggest me what approaches i shall follow for my task, it will be great possi. bly with code example

Get this timeout script running on my complete domain rather than a single webpage. Possibly using cookies or something else.

Comment: I currently have a database storing session data. It has a session id in the form of a random md5, which is stored in a cookie on the user's computer. Basically, there is an "expiry time" in the database, after which the session is deleted from the database. (I don't set a cookie expiry, so when the browser closes, they automatically sign out). Every time a page is loaded, the expiry time is updated in my database - have a script with the JQuery UI, include it on the relevant pages, and have it make an AJAX call to the expiry-update if they click "stay signed in".

Comment: Why don't you just toss this in the JS file in the header in your template or w/e? I think I must be missing something here - it doesn't need to be across domain, if they have clicked on a new page then they have shown activity and the new JS file on the new page takes over and they have another 10 minutes?

Comment: have you considered putting your javascript into another site file, thats automatically included into every page?

Comment: yes i am infact doing that.. but still most of the files are not covered... header.html covers almost 60% files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against javascript and create a complete PHP solution.

This can be achieved simply by giving a user a cookie that expires after 10 minutes on each PHP page. That way, the cookie is renewed with each visit, and if they come back after that ten minutes, the cookie is gone and the system will no longer recognize them.

I would also suggest against sessions, they can get messy easily, and if you want to expand to multiple machines to load balance, it becomes almost impossible to manage. It's not a realistic production tool.

Call this every page - This will check if they already have a cookie, if they do, it will renew it with the same value for ten minutes (60 seconds times ten minutes). You can change the cookie name of 'user' to whatever you want.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
     setcookie('user', $_COOKIE['user'], time()+60*10);

     //put your user validation code here to make sure the cookie is real
     //then you can put your logged in specific data under it.
}
```

To authorize a user in the first place, most likely when they login, you can do this:

```
setcookie('user', $value, time()+60*10);
```

And if you want to log someone out, you can do this:

```
setcookie('user', '', 0);
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Yes please. I would like to try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting their session cookie to expire after 10 minutes. Use [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set the duration of the cookie (first parameter).

```
session_set_cookie_params(600, '/', 'www.example.com', false, false);
session_start();
```

Make sure you call it before `session_start()`.

You would then use JavaScript to check the expires parameter of the cookie. If it is getting close to the expired time you then would use that same JavaScript to show them the dialog warning their session is about to expire

Comment: So i can use this to timout.. but how will i use the alert to notify user for 8 minutes. For that i would need javascript only. Right ? 


Or are you saying i can simply use cookies and need not to use JS at all ?

Comment: You would use JavaScript for the notification but that's all you would need JS for

Comment: so how would i notify my JS that 8 minutes have passed. do i need 2 counters one in JS another in PHP or how would JS know 8 minutes passed since last activity on a domain's page?

Comment: You would use JavaScript to check the `expires` parameter of the cookie. If it is getting close to the expired time you then would use that same JavaScript to show them the dialog warning their session is about to expire. (adding this to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use session and/or cookies for this matter. The way you use them, is that in every page of your website you first check for the cookie/session, and only then proceed. So if your user is logged out once, and attempts to go to another page on the website, he/she will first have to login and only then he can proceed, since the session is no longer available for that user.

Something of this sort -

```
<?php

if( $this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE )
{
    // Login again 
}
else
{
    // Display the page
}

?>
```